# Trying to determine Heart Condition? ECG show no P Wave

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, cardiology

A young woman was at the gym doing great her normal workout. She would spend 45 minutes on the elliptical and then 15 minutes doing weight training. This was the regular routine for her as she did this almost everyday. One day her normal routine turned upside-down. As she finished her elliptical workout and was making her way to the weight machines, she experienced a rapid heart beat. This washould nothing alarming at first because she had experienced this rapid heart beat before. When it happened previously the rapid heartbeat lasted only 10 or 20 seconds. However, this time was different. She experienced the rapid heart beat, but this time the heart beat did not slow down after 20 seconds. The rapid heart beat continued and she began to feel shortness of bread, some pressure I her chest, as well as feeling light-headed. Scared for what might be happening in general she went home called her husband. Frantically she tried to explain how she was feeling and how scared she was. They went to the E.R during her sTay in the ER her heart rate was constantly monitored. For five hours her heart rate remained between 130 and 150 bpm. After 5 hours her heart rate spontaneously returned to a normal rhythm. She was kept overnight In the ER and attending cardiologist prescribed low-dose beta-blockers She was given a number of different test and the results were: -blood pressure normal - hematocrit normal -cholesterol normal She is 34 mother of two. She is of adequate weight and BMI for her age and height. She has regular wellness checkups every year and has never had high cholesterol or hypertension.

Comment: **Personal medical questions and health advice** are off-topic on Biology. We cannot safely answer questions for your specific situation and you should **always consult a doctor for medical advice**.

Comment: This is something that you need to see your doctor for.  Until then, do whatever the ER doctors told you to do.  When you go, take all records from your ER visit with you.  The ER doctors' diagnosis should be on the discharge paperwork they gave you.